# How to ignore beginning of line and parts of a line after filtering with grep

Tags: bash, shell, grep, find

I try to filter out a trace output, located in `/sys/kernel/debug/tracing/trace`, which line content looks like this:

```
 kworker/4:2-1892  [004] ....  2186.662751: rtos_queue_send_from_isr_failed: tstamp:68702870649 queue:0x0b4b0e58
 kworker/4:2-1892  [004] ....  2186.662752: rtos_queue_send_from_isr_failed: tstamp:68702870787 queue:0x0b4b1c18
 kworker/4:2-1892  [004] ....  2186.662752: rtos_queue_send_failed: tstamp:68702872258 queue:0x0b4a7258
 kworker/4:2-1892  [004] ....  2186.662754: rtcpu_vinotify_event: tstamp:68702873824 tag:CSIMUX_STREAM channel:0xff frame:1 vi_tstamp:68702873242 data:0x00000001
 kworker/4:2-1892  [004] ....  2186.662755: rtcpu_vinotify_event: tstamp:68703270221 tag:CHANSEL_PXL_SOF channel:0x00 frame:45313 vi_tstamp:68703269252 data:0x00000001
 kworker/4:2-1892  [004] ....  2186.662755: rtcpu_vinotify_event: tstamp:68703270387 tag:ATOMP_FS channel:0x00 frame:45313 vi_tstamp:68703269257 data:0x00000000
 kworker/4:2-1892  [004] ....  2186.662756: rtcpu_vinotify_event: tstamp:68703270504 tag:CHANSEL_FAULT channel:0x00 frame:45313 vi_tstamp:68703269302 data:0x00000200
 kworker/4:2-1892  [004] ....  2186.662756: rtcpu_vinotify_event: tstamp:68703270903 tag:CSIMUX_STREAM channel:0xff frame:2 vi_tstamp:68703269326 data:0x00000001code:0404
```

In order to filter it, I want to get only events comming from `rtcpu_vinotify_event`, and which tag is not `CSIMUX_STREAM` or  `CHANSEL_PXL_SOF`.

At the moment, I've achieved the following output

```
 kworker/4:2-1892  [004] ....  2186.662755: rtcpu_vinotify_event: tstamp:68703270387 tag:ATOMP_FS channel:0x00 frame:45313 vi_tstamp:68703269257 data:0x00000000
 kworker/4:2-1892  [004] ....  2186.662756: rtcpu_vinotify_event: tstamp:68703270504 tag:CHANSEL_FAULT channel:0x00 frame:45313 vi_tstamp:68703269302 data:0x00000200
```

with the following command

```
cat /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/trace | grep -v -e "rtos_queue_send_failed" -e "rtos_queue_send_from_isr_failed" -e "CSIMUX_STREAM" -e "CHANSEL_PXL_SOF"
```

Anyway, there is some irrelevant information in the output which I'd like to omit in the output (beginning of line until `rtcpu_vinotify_event`, and `tstamp`/`vi_tstamp`), so I'd get something like this:

```
 rtcpu_vinotify_event: tag:ATOMP_FS channel:0x00 frame:45313 data:0x00000000
 rtcpu_vinotify_event: tag:CHANSEL_FAULT channel:0x00 frame:45313 data:0x00000200
```

or, if the `tstamps` are complicated to avoid,

```
 rtcpu_vinotify_event: tstamp:68703270387 tag:ATOMP_FS channel:0x00 frame:45313 vi_tstamp:68703269257 data:0x00000000
 rtcpu_vinotify_event: tstamp:68703270504 tag:CHANSEL_FAULT channel:0x00 frame:45313 vi_tstamp:68703269302 data:0x00000200
```

Lastly, I've included `rtcpu_vinotify_event` messages by excluding `rtos_queue_send_from_isr_failed` and `rtos_queue_send_failed` messages. If there is a way to do it so that its not with exclusion, but inclusion of `rtcpu_vinotify_event` string, it would be much better, or if you find it easier with `find`, I don't have any preference.

Comment: Have you tried [tag:awk]?

Comment: `find` seems like completely the wrong tool here.

Comment: I didn't know about it, although it looks pretty interesting. I'll try it out, so if I get the result I'll update this post. Thanks for the suggestion @oguz-ismail

Comment: Give this one a try:
`awk '/tag:ATOMP_FS/ || /tag:CHANSEL_FAULT/{keep_last=$NF; for(i=5;i<(NF-1);i++) printf("%s ", $i);print keep_last}' yourfile`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do two `grep`'s, one for `rtcpu_vinotify_event` and then remove the matches for `CSIMUX_STREAM` and `CHANSEL_PXL_SOF`.
The result is piped to `sed` to filter out the beginning of the line and `tstamp` / `vi_tstamp`.

```
grep 'rtcpu_vinotify_event' /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/trace | 
  grep -v 'CSIMUX_STREAM\|CHANSEL_PXL_SOF' | 
  sed 's/.*\(rtcpu_vinotify_event: \)tstamp:[0-9]* \(.*\)vi_tstamp:[0-9]* \(.*\)/\1\2\3/'
```

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
| cut -f3- -d:
```

to your command

For the inclusion-exclusion problem, why don't you just

```
| grep rtcpu_vinotify_event
```

instead of the excluding grep -v and its patterns?
The result would be

```
grep rtcpu_vinotify_event /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/trace | grep -v "CSIMUX_STREAM\|CHANSEL_PXL_SOF" | cut -f3- -d:
```

EDITED: (to remove also ts)

```
grep rtcpu_vinotify_event /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/trace | grep -v "CSIMUX_STREAM\|CHANSEL_PXL_SOF" | cut -f3,6- -d:
```

Comment: Regarding the `| cut -f3- -d:` command, it works to remove the beginning. Anyway Freddy's answer removes also the `tstamp`s. Moreover, I've tried the inclusion now with `| grep rtcpu_vinotify_event` and its working good. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You are welcome! Anyway I added the line corrected, to remove tstamp. I found the sed solution a bit complicated